# Factoring a hard polynomial

Tags: factoring

This might seem like a basic question but I want a systematic way to factor the following polynomial:

$$n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n+1.$$

I know the answer but I am having a difficult time factoring this polynomial properly. (It should be $(n^2 + 3n + 1)^2$). Thank you and have a great day!

Comment: You may be interested to compare [Wikipedia's article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials) with the Answers below to match up the techniques described in that article.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In general there's no easy way.  But there are a lot of tricks you can use, and sometimes they work.

For this problem, the [rational root theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem) tells us that if there is a rational root, it must be $\pm 1$.  Evidently it isn't either of these, so there are no rational roots, and therefore no factors of the form $n-q$.

So we are looking for two second-degree factors: $$n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n+1 = (an^2+bn+c)(pn^2+qn+r)$$

But we can see from the coefficient of 1 on the $n^4$ term that $a=p=1$. From the constant term of 1 we have either  $c=r=1$ or $c=r=-1$, so it's really

$$n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n+1 = (n^2+bn\pm1)(n^2+qn\pm1).$$

Equating the  coefficients of the $n^3$ terms on each side, we see that $b+q=6$.

Equating the coefficients of the $n^2$ terms on each side, we see that either $bq+2=11$ (if we take the $\pm$ signs to be $+$) or that $bq-2 = 11$ (if the $\pm$ signs are $-$).

The equations $b+q=6$ and $bq-2 = 11$ certainly have no solution in integers, since one of $b$ or $q$ must be 13.  So we try the other pair of equations, $b+q=6$ and $bq+2 = 11$.  Here the solution $b=q=3$ is obvious, and we are done, except to check the answer.  We must do this, because we have completely ignored  the coefficient of the $n$ term.

Comment: Great solution! Thank you very much @MJD :)

Comment: You are welcome. I am glad you are pleased.

Comment: It is fair to take $a=p=1$, but then it doesn't seem fair to assume $c=r=1$.  It works this time.  If we are factoring over the integers, we can get $c=r=\pm1$

Comment: @Ross Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @RossMillikan Can you explain a little further why you can't assume $c=r=+ or - 1$? I can't see any other possibility for any other polynomial with a coefficient of 1 to the $x^0$ term

Comment: @Ovi: if you don't factor over the integers, you could have $c=2, r=\frac 12$ at this stage of the derivation.

Comment: @RossMillikan Oh sorry haha that was so stupid

Comment: @ovi At the time Ross wrote that comment, I had forgotten to discuss the possibility of $c=r=-1$ in the post.  I added it afterward.

Answer (score 35):

I was thinking along the same lines as TZakrevskiy but with a slight twist.  Once you've become convinced that $P(n)=n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n+1$ is the square of a quadratic (because its values for small $n$ are all squares), try computing

$$P(10)=10000+6000+1100+60+1=17161$$

and then take its square root:

$$\sqrt{17161}=131=1\cdot10^2+3\cdot10+1$$

which suggests the (correct) factorization

$$P(n)=(n^2+3n+1)^2$$

If you want to be extra sure, look at

$$\sqrt{100^4+6\cdot100^3+11\cdot100^2+6\cdot100+1}=10301$$

Comment: +1 as I've never seen this kind of approach used for factorisation before.

Comment: What a smart approach!

Answer (score 21):

Exploit the symmetry of the palindromic polynomial to factorise as follows,

$$\begin{align*}
n^4 + 6n^3 + 11n^2 + 6n + 1
&= n^2\left( n^2 + \frac{1}{n^2} + 6n + \frac{6}{n} + 11 \right)\\
&= n^2\left( (n + 1/n)^2 + 6(n + 1/n) + 9 \vphantom{\frac{1}{n^2}} \right)\\
&= n^2\left( n + 1/n + 3 \right)^2\\
&= \left( n^2 + 3n + 1 \right)^2,\\
\end{align*}$$

having essentially substituted $k = n + \frac{1}{n}$ and used $k^2 - 2 = n^2 + \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Answer (score 7):

Just to add an alternative: From an algorithmic point of view (i.e., to write a program that performs factorization without any intelligence guiding the process), one of the fastest things to check and therefore typically the first step is *squarefree factorization,* by taking gcds of the polynomial and its derivative(s).

$$\begin{eqnarray*} f&=&n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n+1\\ f'&=& 4n^3+18n^2+22+6\\ \gcd(f,f')&=& n^2+3n+1 \end{eqnarray*}$$

Of course, working by hand and with a human brain behind it, the cost analysis may be different from that for a computer and computing gcds may not be as attractive as it is for machines.

Comment: Right, in this case the GCD of the polynomial and its formal derivative gives the complete irreducible factorization.  More generally it identifies any repeated factors quickly.

Answer (score 6):

There's another approach: check that for, say $n=\pm 1,\, 0,\,\pm 2$ your polynomial is a perfect square:$$\begin{cases}25,&n=1\\1,&n=-1\\1,&n=0\\1,&n=-2\\121,&n=2.\end{cases}$$ Therefore,  in five points a polynomial of fourth degree is a perfect square - you can hope to find a polynomial of the second degree that satisfies
$$\begin{cases}\pm 5,&n=1\\\pm 1,&n=-1\\\pm 1,&n=0\\\pm 1,&n=-2\\\pm 11,&n=2\end{cases}.$$

This is an overdetermined system, but, luckily, it has a solution: wlog, we take the candidate as $ n^2+2bn+c$ (because of the coefficient at $n^4$). The value in $n=-1$ gives $1-2b+c = \pm 1$, and in $n=0$ $ c=\pm 1$. By checking $4$ solutions of the obtained $4$ linear systems we can eliminate all but one by testing against remaining points $n$: we obtain $c=1$, $b=3/2$. Finally we check that indeed $(n^2+3n+1)^2=n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n+1 $.

Answer (score 4):

we can reorganize the terms of $n^4+6n^3+11n^2+6n+1$ like $$(n^4+2n^2+1)+(6n^3+6n)+9n^2 $$ $$(n^2+1)^2+6n(n^2+1)+(3n)^2=(n^2+3n+1)^2$$ then we are done

Comment: That regrouping is nice, but can someone edit that _final_ step to show more of how it's done?

Comment: Oh, I see now: the (n^2 +1) can be treated as a term (b), then b^2 + 6nb + 9n^2 can be factored as (b+3n)^2,  then (n^2+1) can be substituted back in.