# How to find the Square Root of a Polynomial

Tags: polynomials, square-numbers

$4x^4 + 4x^3 - 11x^2 -6x + 9$

How do you find the square root of this polynomial? I really don't understand. Please provide an easy-to-understand explanation. Thanks.

Comment: [A  similar problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/684036/25554)

Comment: I apologize for not getting this, but I'm taking Algebra 2 right now. This concept is very new to me, and I have been struggling with it for quite some time now. I think I understand how to get the root of 4x^4 and 9, but I don't understand we acquire the middle term of the answer.

Comment: I suggest that you show us what you already did, and explain where you got stuck. Then people may post answers that will help with your particular difficulty.

Comment: Well, I think it's all making sense now. I just went back to my textbook and read the process which consists of the 'trial divisor' method, and through the help you gave too really brought everything together. Thank you so much!

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324385/algorithm-for-finding-the-square-root-of-a-polynomial/1854191#1854191

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A square root of $4x^4+4x^3-11x^2-6x+9$ would be a polynomial $P(x)$ with the property that $$P(x) \cdot P(x) = 4x^4+4x^3-11x^2-6x+9.$$  We want to find $P(x)$ with this property, or prove that there is no such.
$P(x)$ must have degree 2; since otherwise its square would not have degree 4.  (For example, if $P(x)$ contained an $x^3$ term, then $P(x)\cdot P(x)$ would contain an $x^6$ term, which we don't want.)  If there is such a polynomial, we can write it as $$P(x) = ax^2 + bx  + c$$ for some numbers $a,b,c$.

Now we have $$(ax^2 + bx+ c)^2  = 4x^4+4x^3-11x^2-6x+9.$$

Now you can expand the left side and equate the coefficients of the two sides, obtaining five equations in $a,b,$ and $c$, which are not hard to solve.

Does that help?

Answer (score 2):

If this is the square of some polynomial $ax^2+bx+c$, we find
$$\begin{align}4x^4 + 4x^3 - 11x^2 -6x + 9&= (ax^2+bx+c)^2\\&=a^2x^4+2abx^3+(b^2+2ac)x^2+2bcx+c^2\end{align}$$
By equating coefficients, we find $a^2=4$, hence (as we may play with the sign) wlog. $a=2$. Next, $4=2ab$ gives us $b=1$. Then $-6=2bc$ gives us $c=-3$. We check that all wiorks out, i.e. that $-11=b^2+2ac$ and $c^2=9$.

---

Alternatively, you can make use of the fact that the derivative of $g(x)^2$ is $2g(x)g'(x)$. Hence if $f(x)=g(x)^2$, then $g$ is a common divisor of $f$ and $f'$. Use the euclidean algorithm to find $\gcd(f,f')$:
$$\begin{align}\gcd(f,f')&= \gcd(4x^4 + 4x^3 - 11x^2 -6x + 9,16x^3+12x^2-22x-6)\\&=\gcd(4x^4 + 4x^3 - 11x^2 -6x + 9,8x^3+6x^2-11x-3)\\
&=\gcd(8x^3+6x^2-11x-3,2x^2+x-3)\\
&=\gcd(2x^2+x-3,0)\\
&=2x^2+x-3\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting the coefficient of $x^3,$

$$4x^4+4x^3+\cdots+x^2=(2x^2)^2+2\cdot2x^2\cdot x+x^2$$

Adjusting the coefficient of $x^2$ and the constants
$$4x^4+4x^3-11x^2+\cdots+3^2=(2x^2)^2+2\cdot2x^2\cdot x+x^2-2\cdot2x^2\cdot3+\cdots+3^2$$

Finally,

$$4x^4+4x^3-11x^2-6x+3^2=(2x^2)^2+2\cdot2x^2\cdot x+x^2-2\cdot2x^2\cdot3+3^2-2\cdot x\cdot3=(2x^2+x-3)^2$$

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you just did, please?

Comment: @BrokenMoon, Please find the edited version

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the polynomial is a perfect square, then the square root algorithm works. For example

---

### $$\sqrt{4x^4 + 4x^3 - 11x^2 -6x + 9}$$

\begin{array}{lcccccccccccccc}
&&2x^2 && +x && -3\\
&&---&---&---&---&---\\
  &|& 4x^4 & 4x^3 & -11x^2 & -6x & +9\\
2x^2 && 4x^4\\
&&---&---&---\\
&&& +4x^3 & -11x^2 \\
4x^2+x &|& &+4x^3 &+x^2\\
&&&---&---&---&---\\
&&&& -12x^2 &-6x &+9\\
4x^2+ 2x -3 &|&&&-12x^2 &-6x &+9\\
&&&&---&---&---\\
&&&&&&0\\
\end{array}

\begin{array}{ll}
\text{STEP}\;1. &\text{Compute the square root of the leading term (4x^4) and put it,}\\
& \text{(2x^2), in the two places shown.} \\
\text{STEP}\;2. &\text{Subtract and then append the next two terms ($4x^3-11x^2$).}\\
\text{STEP}\;3. &\text{Double the currently displayed quotient $(2x^2 \to 4x^2)$,} \\
& \text{then add the new term, $x$, so that $x(4x^2 + x)$ will "cancel out" the} \\
& \text{$4x^3$ in $4x^3 -11x^2$.}\\
\text{STEP}\;4. &\text{Subtract and then append the next two terms ($-6x+9$).}\\ 
\text{STEP}\;5. &\text{Double the currently displayed quotient} \\
& \text{ $(2x^2 + x \to 4x^2 + 2x)$, then add a new term, $x$,} \\
& \text{then add a new term, $-3$, so that $-3(4x^2 + 2x - 3)$ will "cancel out"} \\
& \text{ the $-12x^2$ in $-12x^2 -6x + 9$.}
\end{array}