# Factorise $x^4 + 3x^2+ 6x+ 10$

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I need to factorise $x^4 + 3x^2 + 6x + 10$ completely over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I am not sure how to do this. I can't find any roots of this equation in $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Have you tried factorising it into quadratics?

Comment: how can i find such quadratics

Comment: try $(x^2 + A x + B)(x^2 + C x + D)$

Comment: surely i need a root to do this? there will be too many constants?

Comment: $x^4 + 3 x^2 + 6 x + 10 = \left(x^2-2 x+5\right) \left(x^2+2 x+2\right)$

Comment: There are four constants $A, B, C, D$ and you know four coefficients of the result. Also, $BD = 10$, so there are only a few possible choices.

Comment: @cf12418 Use Gauss's lemma. You can factorize it over $\mathbb Q$ if, and only if, you can do it over $\mathbb Z$. Thus Will's hint suffices.

Comment: Related posts, with answers: [1](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/684036) [2](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/785070)

Answer (score 8):

Let :
$$x^4 + 3x^2 + 6x + 10 = (x^2 + ax + b)(x^2 + cx + d)$$

Expanding the right hand side and matching coefficients with the left hand side you need to solve the following equations :
\begin{eqnarray*}
a + c &=& 0 \qquad (x^3)\\
b + d + ac &=& 3 \qquad (x^2)\\
ad + bc &=& 6 \qquad (x)\\
bd &=& 10 \qquad (x^0)
\end{eqnarray*}

Clearly $a = -c$ and then you could try $b = \pm1, d = \pm10$ or $b = \pm2, d = \pm5$ and see what you get for $a$ and $c$.
Something else you can notice from the third equation is that $a(d-b) = 6$. This leads to the fact that $d-b|6$ hence they can't be $\pm1$ and $\pm10$.